# probability misnoma

Tags: probability

There are 3 men let them be $Myself ,X,Y$ out of these $3$ it is given that $2$ will be executed. They are in a custody . I ask the guard whose is going to be executed . so he says he cant tell whole truth so he says X is going to be executed. Now heres where  the doubt is. As X is sure to die my probability of surviving increases from $0.33 $ to $0.50$ but now the book says it isnt so the probability of Y is two times of you to survive. Can someone explain it to me how so?

Comment: This isn't clear, I mean the rules aren't clear.  It sounds like a Monty Hall problem...in that the guard had the ability to chose which of $X,Y$ to name.  But the motives of the guard are unarticulated (unlike the game show host...who will always open a worthless door).

Comment: On what thing do you want the clarification

Comment: What rules govern the guard's response?  I gather he can't lie, but what else?  Again, if this were a Monty Hall problem the guard's response would be restricted to "name a prisoner, not the one asking, who is going to die." That gives the $\frac 23$ answer so reverse engineering suggests this is what is intended.  But, really, it needs to be specified.

Comment: Not mentioned anything about that in the book but if one thinks logically would anyone tell you are going to die ?? That doesnt make sense and yes guard is telling 100% truth

Comment: Well, it seems like a lot to assume.  But if you do assume all that then this is exactly like the Monty Hall problem.  the guard's response carries no information (with respect to the questioner) as it will always be the case that at least one of $X,Y$ is doomed.  Thus the original survival probability of $\frac 13$ is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can think of it like a Monty Hall  problem with a restriction that you cannot switch doors. I.e., what increases your probability to get the prize is the fact that you can (and you will) switch doors. As the probability that you wrong at the first attempt is $2/3$ and by switching doors,  your probability to err decreases to $1/3$. More formally, the conditioned probability that you first failed and then switched to the "prize" door is $\frac{2}{3}\times 1$.

Now, think of it, as you must stick to the first chosen door. In that case you are indifferent to which of the other $2$ doors is "empty". Because you can do nothing with this new information. It is analogues to the prisoners problem, as you cannot change nothing (i.e., the outcome of the game does not depend on your strategy - whether to switch doors or not), so the guard answer bears no information for you. A little bit more formally, without too many arithmetic:

One possible path is that either $A,B$ or $A,C$ will be executed, this happens with probability $2/3$, then the answer of the guard is $C$ or $B$ with probability $1$, and then chances of $A$ to be executed becomes $1/2$. Another path is if $B$ and $C$ are doomed - this happens with probability $1/3$, then the answer of the guard is uniformly random between $B$ and $C$, in either answer the probability of $A$ to be executed becomes $1/2$, so summing up 
$$
\frac{2}{3}\times 1 \times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{2}{3} .
$$

For more detailed explanation see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Prisoners_problem).